# Is there a way to filter out retweets?

Tags: twitter

Too many people are retweeting to the point that I get sick of reading the same stuff again and again.

How can I filter out retweets?

Comment: What app/interface are you using? Tweetdeck supports this, but AFAIK, the standard Twitter site does not.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced). Search for something in the search tool bar and click on the more options tab on the result page and then choose advanced search. Enter the Twitter account into the "from account" field and make sure the "include retweet" check box at the bottom is unchecked. Search and then it returns all tweets from the account without any retweets included.

Comment: The "include retweet" checkbox currently does not exist (anymore?), so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Correction: the checkbox is missing because using advanced search by username now seems to exclude retweets by default.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but the solution is to use the `exclude:retweets` filter.

If you want to see tweets with `#sugar` but no retweets you search for:

```
#sugar exclude:retweets
```

Comment: Hi @Christoffer, great answer, and welcome to Web Applications. I added some formatting to your answer to make it easier to read.

Comment: Hey @Christoffer, this isn't valid anymore. Please have a look at [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146679/255810).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to filter from the web UI all retweets.

What you will need to do is go to each profile you follow, then:

1. Click the gear icon
2. Select **Turn off Retweets**

Do this for every user you follow that you do not want to see what they retweet.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I found the gear icon on their profile, and turned off retweets, but I still see retweets, even after refreshing the user's profile page.  It's maddening that I can't just focus on their occasional actual tweets.

Comment: This setting doesn't affect their profile page AFAIK, just timelines.

Answer (score 3):

There is an upgrade in twitters API: You'll need to use `-is:retweet` to remove all retweets. The parameter `exclude` is not supported anymore.

From https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-rule

> Prepend a dash to a keyword (or any operator) to negate it (NOT). [...] One common query clause is `-is:retweet`, which will not match on Retweets, thus matching only on original Tweets.

Comment: thank you for this answer

Answer (score 1):

I always just use the advanced search filters for tweets from the user which excludes all retweets. Type into the Twitter search bar:

`from:[username]`

and sort by Latest. If you want to exclude replies also, search:

`from:[username] -filter:replies`

Answer (score -2):

use https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/ and then add a filter to exclude retweets